# shutdown and reboot do not work for Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: shutdown, lenovo, ideapad

When I try to shut down Ubuntu 21.04 I have dark window. When I try to reboot I also have a dark window. The computer does not shut down, but Windows 10 shuts down normally. I tried `sudo shutdown -h now` and `sudo systemctl poweroff` but they didn't work.

Lenovo-IdeaPad-S145-15AST. It is new problem. I installed Ubuntu about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the following information: (0) what is the brand and model of your computer? (1) is this a new problem, or have you always had this issue with 21.04? (2) how long ago did you install 21.04? With this, it *might* be possible to see a pattern and offer a solution 

Comment: Lenovo-IdeaPad-S145-15AST, it is new problem, I installed ubuntu about 2 weeks ago